# How to remove non-values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to clean an array and keep only the numeric values of it. This is my attempt.

```
var array = ['5441ec', '37df21', '34d72', 'f3117'];

function normalize(input, scale, offset) {
    input = input.map(Number); //remove non-numeric characters.
    var cleanUp = input.filter(val => $.isNumeric(val) ); 
    return cleanUp.map( values => values * scale + offset );
    console.log(cleanUp);
};

normalize(array, 1, 0);
```

Comment: does it work that way with strings without quotes? please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with `String.replace()` function:

```js
var arr = ['5441ec', '37df21', '34d72', 'f3117'],
    res = arr.map((v) => Number(v.replace(/\D+/g, '')));

console.log(res);
```

---

- `\D+` - one or more non-digit character(s)

Comment: @NinaScholz "Remove non numeric values from the array". Pretty sure this answer fits the description

Comment: it was a bit confusing seeing as the question originally had alpha numeric values in the array w/o wrapping them in quotes to show them as strings @Francisco

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different to RomanPerekhrest's answer using `match` rather than `replace`.

```js
var array = ['5441ec', '37df21', '34d72', 'f3117'];

function normalize(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => Number(el.match(/\d+/)));
};

console.log(normalize(array));
```

Or, if you want to retain the elements as strings, just leave out the number coercion.

```js
var array = ['5441ec', '37df21', '34d72', 'f3117'];

function normalize(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => el.match(/\d+/)[0]);
};

console.log(normalize(array));
```